# How can I make tree schema in MongoDB service using Node js and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-services

I want to create a mat-tree in angular 8 and data should come from the MongoDB database. For this need, I have to make a tree-structured schema in my backend server and then put data in that schema and retrieve it from that schema. Till now I have created mat-tree from local data and made a tree model in my backend server which is as follow:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const treeSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  parent: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Node'
  },
  children: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Node'
  }],
  ancestors: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Node'
  }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Node', treeSchema)
```

I don't know how to put and retrieve data from this schema using API service.
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you just need help on how to create the API endpoints or on how to compose the db queries needed to add and retrieve nodes?

Comment: No, I need to compose the db schema and then retrieve and add data in it using API service.

Comment: I am using Angular8 as my front end. When I create tree-like structure in my MongoDB then I'll interact with that schema using mat-tree

Answer (score 2):

database mongodb and node js server with express

i have found to use document

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose